# Send a link along with an image

Tags: android

I have been developing an app that sends images by intent ,also along with an install button like the following picture in this link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVp8B.jpg

When the user who receives this picture via messenger clicks on the "Install button", google play will open that app.

Does anybody know how to do this ?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you could send the link in `intent.putExtra("key", "your link");` and then, you could `getExtra` and set it when click button in the destination activity

Comment: This is not what I want.please see the image i posted.An "install" button is added to the picture.it's so cool.